# How to access the variable fetched inside .each() method and use it outside in the script in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am getting some result using `.each()` function but I can only access those result/variable inside the `.each()` method. In case I want to use the variable from outside the method in anywhere in the script, how to do that.

Below is my code sample:

```
    var pass_no=[];
        var pass_status=[];
        var pass_cur_status=[];
        var pass_no_j='';
        var pass_status_j='';
        var pass_cur_status_j='';
$.each(result.passengers, function(idx, da){

        //status is available as da.status
            $('#disp_pnr').css('display','none');
            $('#pnr_entries').css("display","none");
            $('#disp_tbl').css("display","");
            pass_no.push(da.no);
            pass_status.push(da.booking_status);
            pass_cur_status.push(da.current_status);

            //$('#disp_tbl').append("<tr><td>Passenger "+da.no+"</td><td>"+da.booking_status+"</td><td>"+da.current_status+"</td></table>");

        });

            pass_no_j = JSON.stringify(pass_no);
            pass_status_j = JSON.stringify(pass_status);
            pass_cur_status_j = JSON.stringify(pass_cur_status);
            console.log("dfdsf"+pass_no_j);
```

Here, I am getting passenger no. in variable `da.no` and `da.booking_status` in `da.current_status`. How must I use it outside the `.each` method.

Comment: Try out by setting a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out by using a global variable concept:

```
var global_idx = ''; // Top of JS

$.each(result, function(idx, da) {
  global_idx = idx;
  console.log(global_idx);
});

console.log(global_idx); // Anywhere in JS
```

This is in a `each()` so last data will be getting in global variable. If you need all, you have to set in array concept.

```
var global_Array = new Array();
$.each(result, function(idx, da) {
   global_Array.push(idx); // storing in array
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(global_Array)); // Anywhere in JS
```

Comment: Working. Thanks

Comment: what if there is more than one value for the result. how to store in this case and how to iterate.

Comment: you van set an array and using push() to store it in array. I have updated answer

Comment: Great. Working. Thanks

Comment: Sinto, Suppose there are 3 parameter which I am getting from the above code like idx.no, idx.status and idx.curr_status and then pushing it to the global variable array idx_no, idx_status and idx_crr_stat respectively, the result coming is like idx_no = [1,2,3,4], idx_status=[a,b,c,d], idx_crr_stat = [m,n,o,p]. Is there any way to fetch the above result like [1,a,m], [2,b,n],[3,c,o] and [4,d,p]. Please suggest is possible.

Comment: how you are pushing it to global array?

Comment: If you done just like `global_Array.push(idx);` the out will be as like as your expectation